# await не ожидает выполнения функции

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, асинхронность

Почему await в данном случае не позволят дождаться функции t и сразу же выводится 0?

```
async function TEST() {
  let a = 0;

  let t = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      a++;
    });
  }

  await t();
  console.log(a);
}
TEST();
```

Answer (score 1):

`await` ожидает только функции, возвращающие Promise, а `t` в вашем примере — другой тип асинхронной функции, использующей колбек.

Работающий вариант, близкий к вашему:

```js
async function TEST() {
  let a = 0;

  const t = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => { a++; resolve(); }, 0);
  });

  await t();
  console.log(a);
}
TEST();
```

Подробнее см. в https://learn.javascript.ru/async

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ, но ваш способ мне не поможет, я не имею возможности писать что-либо в setTimeout

Comment: Тогда вам в стоит подробнее описать в вопросе условия и причины проблемы.

Comment: С радостью сделал бы это, только здесь не совсем удобно, скажите, можно связаться с вами в telegram или facebook?

Comment: Из меня не ахти какой спец, у вас больше шансов, если будете задавать вопросы здесь, вам скорее ответят знающие люди)